# NativeScript - App Builder on iPhone tells me Companion App is not installed when it is

Tags: ios, visual-studio, nativescript, telerik-appbuilder

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 CE, AppBuilder and the Companion app. I deploy to the cloud, scan by QR code, and AppBuilder tells me the companion app is not installed when it clearly is. I reinstalled all apps and restarted all devices for good measure.

This was working until the last update to either AppBuilder or the companion app.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The issue will be addressed in the 2.11.5 version of the Companion App.

Comment: Yes, I filed a support ticket and they said to just use the QR code scanner in the companion app, which can be accessed through a two finger swipe. I did not know that option existed.